# Why was my duplicate flag declined?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

Today I raised a flag against [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601614/how-do-i-open-an-activity-from-fragment), but it was declined.

Firstly, the user gave a very specific problem. Secondly, it was a question which could simply have been avoided by a little bit of Googling.

I told the OP that it was already asked and answered and linked him to a similar question and he replied "thankyou", meaning that he didn't object and most likely accepts and understands my point. Anyone with a bit of background in Android will see that it is a duplicate (concept is the same, he wants to open an `Activity` and he didn't search SO or the internet before posting).

Was this flag rightly denied? I know moderators can make mistakes, so I am not ranting here. Can anyone please look into this?

Comment: Relatively simple. a few people (not moderators) disagreed with you. Not a whole lot you can do about it.

Comment: I can see that but the question is, what do I do? I don't think flagging it again is the best way to go. :/

Comment: It is a dupe but it would probably better to find one which uses fragments and an onItemClick Listener. Do so and I will close it because, yes, there are many dupes of that. My best guess would be that those differences are why the reviewers chose to leave it open

Comment: @rene are you ok with that?

Comment: Not the greatest but I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965828/how-to-send-id-from-fragment-to-activity

Comment: @codeMagic I can't flag it again. But I found this question - [Start an activity from a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478105/start-an-activity-from-a-fragment)

Comment: @Sufian the problem with that is the real question is how to pass the data. So it needs an answer with a `putExtra()`

Comment: I wouldn't want you to flag it again. Anyway, status-completed. Anyway, if you come across something similar, the Android chatroom would be a better place typically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your close flag entered the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review). The 3 members  that handled the [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9524195P) all choose leave open.

With that they declined your flag. Bad luck, hopefully the outcome is better next time.

If you find a better duplicate one of the other members here (maybe [one with a gold-badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306225/why-was-my-duplicate-flag-declined/306226?noredirect=1#comment248126_306225)) will close vote it against the correct duplicate. Some chat rooms are open for these kind of request. Check the room rules first. The [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room has a lot of regulars, almost 24/7, that can help out.

Comment: I disagree. The OP just copy-pasted his code and asked how he could do what he wanted. This is exactly what we discourage at SO. OPs need to show their effort (of comprehending the issue) and also to narrow down the problem so others (in future) can get help. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @Sufian that explanation doesn't describe a duplicate in my opinion.. duplicates are based on question content, not effort put into generating said content..

Comment: @KevinB please suggest another flag because it clearly is a bad fit for SO. Isn't it?

Comment: It might not need a flag, if it isn't a duplicate (i'm not arguing that it is or isn't a duplicate, I have no expertise in the subject matter). If it's low quality, and/or is lacking research, that's what downvotes are for.